# Send $_POST array using ajax with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have multiple input fields with the name `Change[xxx]`.  The original way is when an update button is clicked, it normally sends the data and updates the database.  But how do I pass this `Change[xxx]` data if I use Ajax? I want to do this *without* jQuery.

The HTML:

```
<input type='text' name='Change[name]' value='Bob' onblur='updateField($id)'></input>
```

Retrieving the info in PHP:

```
foreach($_POST['Change'] as $field => $value) {
    if($field == 'name') {
        // update database
    }
}
```

The JavaScript:

Using `request.send(...)`, this is where I'm not sure how to send the data.

```
function updateField(id) {
    …
    var url = 'orders.php?id='+ id;
    request.open('POST', url, true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    var val = document.getElementsByName("Change[name]")[0].value;
    request.send("id=" + id + "&Change[" + val + "]"); 
    …
}
```

Comment: Psst: it’s just `<input>` or `<input />`, not `<input></input>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly the same as you usually would:

```
request.send("id=" + id + "&Change[name]=" + encodeURIComponent(val));
```

The brackets aren’t special to HTTP, only to PHP.

Comment: You should also call `encodeURIComponent` on `Change[name]=`, as the brackets should be encoded.

Comment: Well, that was a silly mistake I made.  Thanks for your help.  Now I now know to use encode as well.